# sublime: highlight unrecognized symbols

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I wish to find a way that sublime gives unrecognized function calls different color. I love this in phpStorm.

```
$this->rightFunctionName(); has a color
$this->wrongFunctionName(); has different color
```

Comment: ST highlighting is based on scopes being applied. These scopes are defined by series of regular expression patterns. There is no inspection of what is valid and what is invalid (in the scope of a project), so what you are trying to do is not possible in ST.

Comment: no package does that?

Comment: The scope based highlighting is part of the editor itself, so a plugin can't really change it. The closest you could get (as far as I know) is to have a plugin do the inspection (similar to what plugins like SublimeCodeIntel do), and create a highlighted region around the text if it is not found during that inspection. That being said, I don't know of any plugin that does anything like that.

Comment: skuroda, isn't both of your comments actually the perfect answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

ST highlighting is based on scopes being applied. These scopes are defined by series of regular expression patterns. There is no inspection of what is valid and what is invalid (in the scope of a project), so what you are trying to do is not possible in ST.

The scope based highlighting is part of the editor itself, so a plugin can't really change it. The closest you could get (as far as I know) is to have a plugin do the inspection (similar to what plugins like SublimeCodeIntel do), and create a highlighted region around the text if it is not found during that inspection. That being said, I don't know of any plugin that does anything like that.